# Python Log Parsing

Tags: python, string, parsing, iteration

I am new to parsing in Python. I have a log file of the following format:

```
<20>1 2008-12-18T09:46:28.806-07:00 NET-RT - RT_FLOW_CREATE [os@2243.1.1.1.2.43 source-address="192.168.30.170" source-port="55256"] vlan.192 <21>1 2008-12-18T09:46:28.806-07:00 NET-RT - RT_FLOW_CREATE [os@2243.1.1.1.2.43 source-address="192.168.30.170" source-port="55256"] vlan.192
```

The several log entries are on the same line, not separated by "\n".
The log entries start with the format <20> ... <21> .... and they are all on the same line.

How to iterate over the different numbered tags and then extract the following information for each iteration:

Time = 2008-12-18T09:46:28.806-07:00

source-address = 192.168.30.170

source-port = 55256

Comment: Have you tried anything?

Comment: Comment regarding terminology: There is just one log entry per line. Each log entry has fields (timestamp, source, ...). You want to know how to split a log entry into fields.

Comment: @AaronDigulla In the input the OP provides, there actually are 2 log entries in the same line, one begins with `<20>`, the other with `<21>`

Comment: I don't get the closing votes, isn't this legitimate question?

Comment: @mu無 - I don't think it's clear whether the OP's sample is formatted the way he intended it to be.  It might be that everything he's showing us really is ALL on one line; or it may be that each "<dd>" is the start of a new line and he couldn't get it to format that way.

Comment: @Ever can you show some more lines of log file. I want to see whether the format is consistent or not ?!

Comment: I guess I have to learn to stop writing detailed and helpful answers to questions, if there's any chance at all the question is going to be downvoted before I can get the answer finished.  =P

Answer (score 2):

from reading your sample log i can see that you do indeed have several log entries on each line, each with several fields.

how you read the data from the file is a question of choice, and dependent on how big these logs are as to whether they would be too big for memory, personally i would open the file and then work on it line by line using `file.readline()`

then if you split each file using < as a separator - e.g. `line.split("<")` it should split each line into several parts depending on how many entries are there.

then you could perform a further split on each fragment using whitespace as a separator - e.g. `part.split()`

so using your sample log that would give:

```
[
[
'20>1', # first sub list
'2008-12-18T09:46:28.806-07:00',
'NET-RT',
'-',
'RT_FLOW_CREATE',
'[os@2243.1.1.1.2.43',
'source-address="192.168.30.170"',
'source-port="55256"]',
'vlan.192'
],
[
'21>1', # second sub list
'2008-12-18T09:46:28.806-07:00',
'NET-RT',
'-',
'RT_FLOW_CREATE',
'[os@2243.1.1.1.2.43',
'source-address="192.168.30.170"',
'source-port="55256"]',
'vlan.192',
]
]
```

as you can see this returns a list of lists, with each of the sublists being broken up into individual fields contained in a single log entry.

so now all you have to do is extract from each list the bits you wanted, if the logs are always going to be in the same form you could do this simply using the index, but a more robust way to do it would be through matching strings.

Answer (score -1):

1. Read the file, line by line
2. Split lines by separator, seems like '>' could be separator
3. Split the each line, and add your collection

Very short and simple example:

```
for log in open('my.log').readlines():
  for line in log.split('>'):
    data = line.split()
    print(data)
```

For more complicated parsing, I would use regular expression (re module).

Comment: Did you read the question?

Comment: Yes, fixed this solution.